# Deploy vue app with backend on shared hosting

Tags: laravel-5, deployment, vue.js

It is possible to deploy VueJS app with laravel backend on shared hosting without ssh ? If  yes, how to do that ?

Comment: Not quite sure about your question. Do you want to know how to get your files on the server or are you thinking about something else?

Comment: You can upload all files via ssh or for example desktop program filezilla or whatever you want.

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56164398/4479395) answer.