# How to deploy a Laravel-Vue project on shared server (GoDaddy)

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

This is the first time I am developing a `Laravel Vue app`. When I use `php artisan serve`, everything works fine. But when I load it with `http://localhost/myProject/public`, assets are not loaded. My images are in `img` directory inside public folder. I was using blade templating to manage this issue when I use Laravel alone. But now I can't use blade since it is a `Vue` component. How can I run the project without `php artisan serve`? My Ultimate aim is to deploy the project in godaddy shared server. Please help me.

Comment: https://dev.to/asapabedi/deploying-laravel-5-applications-on-shared-hosting-without-the-use-of-ssh--16a6

Comment: Thank you brother, I have successfully deployed and half of my problem was solved. My project is done using Laravel and Vue. So now I can't send api request, gives a 404 error.

Comment: check my new added answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debug your application using 'php artisan serve' while you develop from your local machine.

When you publish it into godaddy,
compress the project folder (say 'my_project') and upload the zip file ('my_project.zip') to 'public_html' directory in godaddy.

unzip the folder.

Now the directory structure will be 'public_html/my_project...'

you will have a 'public' directory inside 'my_project'.
Now create a subdomain which points to the 'public' directory.

That's it. Now load the subdomain.
The assets and api's will work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

just run`git clone [your_project_address]` in the `www` folder and then run 'php artisan migrate', of course, you should have configured well.

Answer (score 0):

@ThasheelApps this is your solution to access api's.

Create a `.htaccess` file in `root folder` and paste the following code there:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This issue occurs many times due `index.php` in url. if you try your `api endpoint` including `index.php`, it will work perfectly. to prevent this issue we need to follow above soution `htaccess`

Comment: Thank you, But unfortunately it did n't work for me. Still gives me the following error.

app.js:1 GET http://my_domain/api/profile 404 (Not Found)
app.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404

Comment: try `get` API in browser URL eg: `my_domain/index.php/api/profile`. Does it work?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. zip your project after npm run dev and php artisan serve without
   any error.
2. Go to your shared hosting location and outside fo public_html
   make a folder name say myproject. Inside this folder extract all
   your project files.
3. cut your public folder from  project folder on root, go to your
   subdomain folder under public_html and paste.
4. go to index.php inside public folder and 
       require **DIR**.'/../vendor/autoload.php'; and
       $app = require_once **DIR**.'/../bootstrap/app.php'; pointing to your project location on root.

That is all. Enjoy, if you have properly created and attached your DB to your project.